# Casting as INT64 from CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

Good afternoon. I have a table in which all the columns are in string format. To clarify, the 'null' is a string, not an empty value in the table.

| install_date | app_id | value | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | id12345 | 0 | 'null' |
| 2021-01-02 | id12345 | 'null' | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | id12345 | 1 | 5 |

I have to do two things: convert the 'null' string into 0, then cast that as int64. I have a query below, but I am receiving errors in relation to my syntax: **Syntax error: Unexpected ")**.

```
SELECT 
install_date, 
app_id, 
cast((case when value = 'null' then '0' else value) as int64) as value
cast((case when revenue = 'null' then '0' else revenue) as int64) as revenue
```

Any idea what I should do? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff thank you for your reply. I get this error: Syntax error: Unexpected ")". So my syntax is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you posted the actual query that you're trying to execute, I see that you're missing the `END` keyword on both your `CASE` statements and a `,` after `value`, on line 4.

```sql
SELECT
    install_date,
    app_id,
    CAST((CASE value WHEN 'null' THEN '0' ELSE value END) AS int64) AS value,
    CAST((CASE revenue WHEN 'null' THEN '0' ELSE revenue END) AS int64) AS revenue
FROM
    DATA
```

Comment: Hello. This did the trick! What a silly mistake. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @vtrhmd . . . That doesn't actually make sense.  This is the same logic as in your question, just with a different style of `case` -- which should not affect the type conversions at all.

Comment: While it's true that I simplified the `CASE` a bit, the point here is that his original statement was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are getting type conversion errors.  I would suggest instead:

```
select coalesce(safe_cast(value as int64), 0),
       coalesce(safe_cast(revenue as int64), 0)
```

Of course, you might want to investigate what other non-number values are in the column:

```
select distinct value, revenue
from t
where safe_cast(value as int64) is null or
      safe_cast(revenue as int64) is null;
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. To clarify, the 'null' is a string, not an empty value. So I don't actually want to skip any columns. I believe I have to convert the 'null' to 0 first, then cast everything as int64. For this table, the only non-number values are 'null' string. The rest are numbers in a string format.